# ng-repeat not working in MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, express, mean

I am new to MEAN stack and i was trying to make a simple contact app. But ng-repeat in my index.html is not working. Here is my code. Files are according to default file structure provided by Express

**index.html**

```
    <html ng-app="myApp" xmlns:ng="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <title>First Application x</title>
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"> </script>

    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
          <h1>Phone Directory</h1>
          <table class="table">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Phone</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                     <td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></input></td>
                     <td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email"></input></td>
                     <td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Phone No." ></input></td>
                     <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Add Contact</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
                   <td class="info">{{ contact.name }}</td>
                   <td class="info">{{ contact.email }}</td>
                   <td class="info">{{ contact.phone }}</td>
                   <td class="info">{{ contact.phone }}</td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
          </table>
     </div>
     <script src="/javascripts/controllers/controller.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**controller.js**

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('/contactlist').success(function(response){
        $scope.contactlist = response;
        console.log(response);
        console.log("Hello World from controller");
    });

    }]);
```

**index.js**

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    /* GET home page. */

    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: '' });
    });

    router.get('/contactlist',function(req,res){
    person1={
        name: 'Tim',
        email: 'Tim@gmail.com',
        phone: '111 111 -1111'
    };
    person2={
        name: 'Tim cook',
        email: 'timcook@gmail.com',
        phone: '222 111 -1111'
    };
    person3={
        name: 'Tim Baron',
        email: 'barrontim@gmail.com',
        phone: '222 333 -1111'
    };
    var contactlist=[person1,person2,person3];
    res.json(contactlist);
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: are you getting any error on console? if yes then pls post

Comment: @kapil.dev no ..on console I am not getting any error

Comment: enter following url on ur browser and let me know what is displays

localhost:{port}/contactlist

if port is 3000
eg : http://localhost:3000/contactlist

Comment: @kapil.dev   I am getting the person's contacts in json format that I have provided in the index.js file.

Comment: @ayush 
print '$scope.contactlist' instead of 'response' now can you see the same json response in the console of index.html ?

Comment: @kaiil.dev yeah on the console json response is showing but still not showng on the index page

Comment: @Ayush posted in the answer section and sry for the late response. Hope it works

Comment: @AayushGoyal What do you mean by «Not working» ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright!!

From express app you are passing JSON String so when you receive in ajax call it is JSON String and you need to decode into object.It can be done using JSON.parse() function.

Replace your line with below one

```
$scope.contactlist = JSON.parse(response);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: He already receive a JSON formatted array. AngularJS can work with this JSON directly